# Best Free Web Statistics and Analytics Packages For Sites Using PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, analytics, mysql, statistics

I'm looking for a list of the best free web statistics and analytics packages for my site using PHP & MySQL?

Answer (score 10):

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) is pretty much the best around, regardless of server platform. Unless there is a specific reason you need to use server-side analytics rather than a client-side Javascript solution, Google Analytics is the way to go.

Comment: I agree Google Analytics is very, very good. However I find in some cases that large businesses aren't too keen about having their data stored on Google's (or any third party servers).

Comment: I think it's good to have self-hosted options, but you really don't need to worry about having your data stored on Google's servers. I mean, if these are documents that relate to national security or otherwise have a high risk of being targeted by corporate espionage, then yes, you should find a more secure solution. But if you're already using a commercial hosting provider, then it's a moot point. And even if you're self-hosted, your ISP and other upstream networks still have access to your site's analytics data.

Comment: Google Analytics is a probably the best free and cheap to implement choice.  I don't think there is anything better that is free and cheap to implement.  If you want to host it yourself or get the "best" solution then GA isn't really a choice.  It really depends on what you want.

Comment: @Lèse majesté, I agree with you but this can become a difficult decision for businesses who are competing with Google at a certain level.

Answer (score 4):

http://piwik.org/ is a good option if you're looking for self-hosting.

Comment: Agreed wholeheartedly if you don't want Google hosting all your data Piwik is great.